# Licence check for a pro key

Tags: android, android-lvl

So I would like to make a free app with full functionality loaded in. The pro functionality will be disabled until the app detects a licensed pro key. And of course I would like to have the pro key check it's licence using LVL. While I know how to do things right until this point, I don't know how to make the pro key communicate with the app that it should enable the pro functionality.

Here's the main app code (com.test.mainapp):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    context = getApplicationContext();

    final PackageManager pacman = getPackageManager();
    final int signatureMatch = pacman.checkSignatures(getPackageName(),
            "com.test.mainapp_key");

    if (signatureMatch == PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Pro key detected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Free version", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

While this stops others making fake keys for my app, they still can share the key app online to others and it will work. Because we can't do the LVL check from another application, I would want the licence key app check it's own licence and if it's correct, only then the user gets the pro functionality. How can I have the licence key app and the main app communicate to each other like this?

The functionality I'm trying to get here is like Titanium Backup does, for example.

Comment: If you can get a unique ID for the device (e.g. IMEI or device serial number) you could use a serial number that is tied to that value. That would make the serial key invalid for any device but the one you licensed.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more how would the logic in this work?

Comment: Let's say you have a secret key, for example: `mySecretKey`. You get the device ID as a string, e.g. `MyDevice`. Concatenate the two and hash the result using MD5 (or your own hash scheme) and use a portion of the hash as your key. To verify, simply compute the hash for `mySecretKey` and the current device ID and compare against the serial. If it matches, the serial is valid for this device. On another machine, it won't ever match because the device ID is wrong.

Comment: Obviously this could be broken by reverse engineering your app, but we're talking about trivial licensing here, not full-blown DRM.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can send intents between the main app and the key app. If you are using LVL in the key app then an example callback would be:

```
private class MyLicenseCheckerCallback implements LicenseCheckerCallback {
    public void allow() {
        Log.i("Key", "License Accepted");
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("intent.to.call.on.success");
        i.putExtra("licenseresult", 0);
        c.sendBroadcast(i);
        mChecker.onDestroy();
    }

    public void dontAllow() {
        Log.e("Key", "License Denied");
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("intent.to.call.on.failure");
        i.putExtra("licenseresult", 1);
        c.sendBroadcast(i);
        mChecker.onDestroy();
    }

    public void applicationError(ApplicationErrorCode errorCode) {
        Log.i("Key", "LR Error");
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("intent.to.call.on.error");
        i.putExtra("licenseresult", 2);
        c.sendBroadcast(i);
        mChecker.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

You would set up broadcast receivers in both apps to initiate the license check and handle the result. e.g.

```
public class License extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals("intent.called.to.initiate.request")) {
                // Initiate the license request here (possibly using a service)
        return;
    }
}

}
```

You should limit access to the intents using certificate based permissions to prevent other apps being able to send spoofed "License Success" intents.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#Permissions

Short version.

Define permission in manifest

```
< permission android:name="my.package.LicenseCheck" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

Use Permission in receiver declaration:

```
<receiver android:name="name.of.your.receiver" android:permission="my.package.LicenseCheck"> 
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="name.of.intent"/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This was what I was thinking, but I don't know how to prevent other apps firing those intents. Could you provide me some info how to limit the access (that's kind of what I was originally looking for)?

Comment: Try this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#Permissions

Short version. Define permission in manifest

    <permission android:name="my.package.LicenseCheck" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

Use Permission in receiver declaration:
    <receiver android:name="name.of.your.receiver" 
              android:permission="my.package.LicenseCheck">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="name.of.intent"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

Comment: I actually read that page last night, but didn't check the protectionLevel attribute documentation. Thank you. Please edit your previous answer to have that comment in it, so I can mark this question answered : )

Comment: one more thing. I'll obviously use the LVL check inside an IntentService, not a BroadcastReceiver, right?

Comment: Thats how I did it.

1. Main app sent request to license app
2. License app starts service that requests LVL
3. License Service responds to Main app

Comment: Can you guys tell me how you handled the onDestroy?  I chose the IntentService myself, but I'm having issues with the lifecycle and the binding of the licensing server.

Answer (score 1):

### @MainApp

```
<permission android:name="myapp.permission.RESPOND" protectionLevel="signature" />

<receiver android:name=".receiver.WhichHandlesValidationResponse" android:permisssion="myapp.permission.RESPOND">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="myapp.action.VALIDATION_RESPONSE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

### @KeyApp

```
<uses-permission android:name="myapp.permission.RESPOND" />
```

Create LvlValidationHandler.class that contains:

```
Intent i = new Intent("myapp.action.VALIDATION_RESPONSE");
sendBroadcast(i);
```