# Approach to convert donate application to key

Tags: android

I've a Free/Donate versions of my opensource application on playstore.The problem currently I'm facing is duplication of work. Because of two different packages, whenever I update my free version, I need to update my donate version. Both versions are exactly the same in functionality perspective and only the packages are different.

I'm thinking of converting the donate application as donate key. But not sure How strategically move all the donate users to free version. Because it's fully functional app.

BTW, the donate user base is around 1000+

Any help would be greatly appreciated ! I'm not sure whether this question can fit in SO. Please feel free to move it to relevant stackexchange.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034683/licence-check-for-a-pro-key

Comment: Can you clearly identify the difference between the donate version and the free version? If there is NO difference, then just work on your free version and before publishing, Android tools > Change Package Name to generate the update for the donate version.

Comment: @Sherif elKhatib, Most likely, that's what he has already been doing all this time.

Comment: Did you consider this? http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects. I have apps with 4 different "flavors" but all based on the same code base. All I have to do is change the version code in the manifest for each library project and build four different apks. Of course it's more work but it's "only" deployment work while the development is done once for all flavors of the app.

Answer (score 2):

I would do the reverse.

I'd make the donate version (app B) a free app with in-app purchases for donations (and I'd maintain several donation levels). And I'd mark all the current users as donors. This way, these users (who actually gave you money) don't have to move anywhere (this is what I would expect when I'm a paid user).

And I'd ask the users of the free version (app A) to move to the donate version (app B). I'd just mark the old version (for legacy devices) and I would only give updates to (app B). People who haven't donated anything will understand that they need to migrate to the new app if they want the new features. It's what they'd expect.

The drawback to this is that you'd lose the recorded number of downloads and positive reviews associated with your original free app, which must be pretty significant (although, technically you could keep that app around as an app for legacy devices indefinitely).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you mentioned I don't want to loose the stats. I was thinking on the reverse way considering the userbase on free/donate.